# Force website cache update

Tags: html, caching, browser, web, browser-cache

my website is not refreshing when you visit it again, even if i did updates.

I'm using the

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

but seems really not working, expecially with Chrome. Any helps with it?

Thank you very much

Comment: As A first step to help you debug this try manipulating the URL a bit with made-up params when you are  testing this.     www.mysite.com ? RealParam=A & ThisParamMadeUp=Z      Then switch the Z to a Y and see if the cache behaves as expected.  This will tell you if you have another cache mechanism in place such as a corporate proxy server.   I always bury a non visible tmestamp or page incrementer in my page body content to detect this problem so that I can see that I am looking at a cached page and not the page my server would have served next.

Comment: mmmm i'm absolutely out from what you said... :| something easier? :D